# sql join clause is not returning expected results with arabic text

Tags: join

I really been working to solve this problem for quite a while, I have 2 tables with the same structure as follows:

**registerationNumber int, CompanyName nvarchar, areaName nvarchar,phoneNumber int , email nvarchar, projectStatus nvarchar**

All columns with data type nvarchar contains Arabic text except the email column,
tableA contains 675 rows and tableB contains 397 rows all exists in tableA
What I am trying to do is select the non matching rows from tableA,
they should be 675 - 398 = 277 rows

everytime I run the where clause I get all tables returned

The join clause I am writing is like this:

```
select a.registerationNumber
from tableA a left outer join tableB b
on a.registerationNumber = b.registerationNumber
```

but I am not getting any results, I tried all types of joins but I am getting the same results.

I created a sample database and inserted English data in the tables and it worked fine with the following clause:

```
select * from tblAllProjects a right join tblhalfProjects h 
on a.registerationNumber = h.registerationNumber
```

which means that I am writing the correct the correct syntax,
I know that I should use the following syntax on selecting Arabic text:

```
Select * from tableA where comanyName like N'arabic_text'
```

Anyone knows what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: Why are you doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, and in your sample a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` ?

Comment: In your question, you are selecting all rows from `tableA`, and try to find (LEFT OUTER JOIN) records in `tableB`.  you should filter (use a WHERE clause) to filter out the records that are not found.  (HINT: add `WHERE b.registerationNumber IS NULL`) to your query (not the query from the sample database!)

Comment: I copied the last query from the query editor, however I tried all types of joins to check the result set I am getting and it doesn't change I only get all rows from table A or all rows from table B no matter the type of join I am using.

Comment: @luuk I tried to filter the dataset by adding where clause to the uery and I still getting the same reults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant to say that you should do:

```
select a.registerationNumber
from tableA a left outer join tableB b
on a.registerationNumber = b.registerationNumber
where b.registrationNumber is NULL
```

This should select all registrationNumbers from tableA, with no match in tableB.

another way to write this (but probably slower) is:

```
select a.registerationNumber
from tableA a 
where a.registerationNumber not in (
   select b.registerationNumber
   from tableB )
```

You should/can use this second approach if there are only "*a few*"  records returned from the sub-query.

Comment: you know that worked absolutely fine :)
Exactly what I wanted, filtering the query with where clause did work, I never tried to use the subquery for performance issues however I tried this approach but I was comparing the registerationNumber like this : 

WHERE a.registerationNumber != b.registerationNumber

Thank you so much for such a great help